# How do i get performance trend charts on jenkins using publish performance test result plugin?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, jenkins, performance-testing

I am building a solution on jenkins for which i need to have performance trend charts and for that purpose i am using 'Publish performance test result report' plugin of jenkins.

[image]
 In configuration part of jenkins i have selected report type as 'Junit' and in the 'report files' field have given the path of the report.xml. The report looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<junit>
 <testframe test_name="tests">
   <response>0.01</response>
   <throughput>7.37</throughput>
 </testframe >
 <formatter type="xml" />
</junit>
```

Now i get three charts as throuput , response and percentage error but all of them are empty, there is nothing inside these graphs[image]

So, please clarify what am i missing is the report format not correct ? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting performance test report for j-meter result file(.jmx file).

1)Have run the below command to execute  .jmx file.
**./jmeter -n -t < Your_jmx_File_Path.jmx > -l < output_File_Format.csv >**

2)Have configured .csv file in publish performance trend plugin to get the result as chart and as well as csv file. (Kindly check the atta[image]ched screenshot.)

3)Enjoy the graph as per your description in .jmx file.

Answer (score 0):

Got hit by this recently (Jenkins 2.235.5 and Performance plugin 3.18) and found a solution if you get no trends in your graphs.

The key to get trends and graphs working is to make sure that your JMeter runs produce output-files with the same name that stays static between builds. I use a plugin with Gradle that runs JMeter and creates filenames with a date and timestamp for the output filename by default, which caused this problem for me. A simple step in the pipeline where the filename is renamed to something static before running the perfReport-step solved it.